# ¿ Como corregir problemas entre filtros de WooCommerce y mi código personalizado?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theme, función-personalizada

Estoy tratando de ocultar los precios y el boton de comprar de algunas categorias de la tienda, y para ello nos ayudaron con una función para poder hacer esto.

Pero no puedo hacerlo por que hay código del tema que uso que impide que mi propio código haga el efecto deseado.

¿ Como puedo corregir la incompatibilidad entre código ?
La verdad es que hemos probado con varios metodos, y ninguno funciono, vean alguna de las opciones que hemos utilizado:

primera opción que utilicé:

```
add_filter(
  'woocommerce_get_price_html',
  'hide_price_and_button_for_category',
  10, 2
);

function hide_price_and_button_for_category($price, $product) {
  if (
    has_term('herramientas', 'product_cat', $product->get_id())
  ) {
    // If the product belongs to "your-category-slug" category
    $price = '';
    remove_action(
      'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
      'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',
      30
    );
  }
  return $price;
}
```

segunda opción que utilicé:

```
function ocultar_precios_y_compra_en_categoria( $price, $product ) {
  // Aquí puedes reemplazar "nombre-de-tu-categoria" por
  // la categoría que deseas ocultar
  if (
    has_term( 'herramientas', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() )
  ) {
    $price = '';
    remove_action(
      'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
      'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',
      30
    );
  }
  return $price;
}

add_filter(
  'woocommerce_get_price_html',
  'ocultar_precios_y_compra_en_categoria',
  10, 2
);
```

Incluso una tercera opción:

```
add_action(
  'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
  'hide_prices_button_category',
  1
);

function hide_prices_button_category() {
  global $product;
  $hide_categories = array( 'fontaneria', 'herramientas' );
  // Reemplaza 'categoria1' y 'categoria2' por
  // las categorías que deseas ocultar.

  if (
    has_term( $hide_categories, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() )
  ) {
    remove_action(
      'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
      'woocommerce_template_single_price',
      10
    );
    remove_action(
      'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
      'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',
      30
    );
    echo '<p>Este producto no está disponible para la venta en esta categoría.</p>';
  }
}
```

Finalmente, un colega reviso el sitio y dedujo que estas funciones no funcionaban, es debido a que el tema que utilizo un filtro propio para mostrar el botón Agregar al carrito, y por ello los métodos no hacen efecto.

Encontre el archivo que utiliza El Tema para manejar el tema del boton de carrito y es el siguiente.
Pero el problema es que no se detectar que es lo que esta impidiendo por parte del archivo del tema, que se ejecute mi código.

Claro, lo ideal seria modificar mi código, ya que si modifico el código del tema, cuando se actualice perder los cambios.

¿ Cual es la parte de código del tema que impide que se ejecute mi función ?
¿ Como corregir cualquiera de las funciones personalizadas para evitar este problema ?

Comment: en un child theme podes ir probando `remove_filter` por cada `add_filter` copiando el nombre y la prioridad para quitar los filtros del theme y reemplazarlos por unos propios. lo mismo con los `remove_action` usando `add_action` con el mismo nombre, prioridad y cantidad de parametros. nota la margen hay unos cuantos `if(tema_option(` "sueltos" dependiendo de qué haga la funcion `tema_option` tal vez convenga meterlas todas dentro de un action ( tal vez [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) ? )

Comment: Gracias por tu buena idea @aloMalbarez,  Revise, compare, hice pruebas y encontre como corregirlo y anular el código del tema. Aun quiero hacer más cambios, pero por el momento esta funcionando. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontre una solución. A sugerencia de @aloMalbarez, busque los archivos que podían estar causando el conflicto, repase los filtros y elimine hasta encontrar el correcto.
Duplique este archivo en mi tema hijo y aunque quiero hacer mejoras y añadir más funcionalidad, por el momento quiero compartir estos logros  por si llegara algún otro usuario con las mismas dudas.

Esta es la conclusión un poco detallada:

```
    // Este fragmento reemplazará el precio por el texto personalizado configurado aquí 
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wwpp_restricted_category_for_non_wholesale__price_html', 9999, 2 );
function wwpp_restricted_category_for_non_wholesale__price_html( $price, $product ) {
    
    if ( is_non_wholeale_and_restricted_category($product) ) {
        $price = '<div><a href="' . get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Contacte para más información', 'bbloomer' ) . '</a></div>';
    }
    return $price;
 
}
 
//Este fragmento eliminará el botón Agregar al carrito 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'wwpp_restricted_category_for_non_wholesale__add_to_cart_button', 9999, 3 );
function wwpp_restricted_category_for_non_wholesale__add_to_cart_button( $add_to_cart, $product, $args ) {
    
    if ( is_non_wholeale_and_restricted_category($product) ) {
        $add_to_cart = '';
    }
    return $add_to_cart;
 
}
 
// Esto establecerá los productos que pertenecen a la categoría de producto seleccionada como no adquiribles 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'wwpp_restricted_category_for_non_wholesale__is_purchasable', 9999, 2 );
function wwpp_restricted_category_for_non_wholesale__is_purchasable( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
    
    if ( is_non_wholeale_and_restricted_category($product) ) {
        $is_purchasable = false;
    }
    return $is_purchasable;
 
}
 
// Este fragmento restringirá la categoría de producto seleccionada para que solo esté disponible para los roles seleccionados 
function is_non_wholeale_and_restricted_category( $product ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $allowed_roles = array( 'shop_manager', 'administrator' );//actualizar roles que pueden ver el precio y agregar al carrito
 
    return ! array_intersect( $user->roles, $allowed_roles ) && has_term( 'herramientas', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ? true : false ;//reemplace el nombre-de-tu-categoria por el slug de categoría de producto que desea que otros roles oculten, excepto el establecido en $allowed_roles
   // reemplace el nombre-de-tu-categoria por el slug de categoría de producto que desea que otros roles oculten, excepto el establecido en $allowed_roles
}
```